# Deriving reload speed formula with exponential decrease

Tags: exponential-function, game-theory

I'm trying to reverse design one good old game and got stuck on deriving the formula of ranged weapon reload speed (I'm not really good at math yet :) ).

I know :

- crossbowman ballistic skill (BS). The more the skill level the less time it takes to reload a weapon.
- Reload time of crossbow modified by crossbowman skill level

I do not know :

- Crossbow base reload speed (I assume it is a fixed value)

Here is in-game [test data of reload speed vs ballistic skill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONzuL.png)
My problem is that I can't figure out how reload time differ so much for BS low levels values (1 and 2)?

The best formula I came up with is:

Reload time = -a*BS + weapon reload speed

But it lacks this exponential reload time decrease for low vs high BS levels. So I wonder how this can be achieved thanks to math?

Comment: Do fitting on an inverse power law $t=a/BS +b$

Comment: thanks! Much appreciated